# Connect computer to internet via ethernet cable to WiFi-connected computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

I have two computers:

- Computer A with a Wi-Fi adapter, connected to the Internet, running Windows 7
- Computer B with no Wi-Fi adapter, not connected to the Internet, dual-booting Windows 7 and Debian

I would like to connect Computer B to the internet by connecting it to Computer A, via USB or Ethernet, etc. Both computers have Ethernet adapters.

How can I do this?

Comment: You might use Internet Connection Sharing (Windows): https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10  or a crossover Ethernet cable: https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Computers-Together-with-an-Ethernet-Cable

Comment: What OS ?  Also, does computer A have an Ethernet adaptor ?

Comment: @davidgo Clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is exactly what you want: http://www.countrymilewifi.com/how-to-share-computers-wifi-with-ethernet-devices.aspx

In short:

1. On computer A, open the Properties of your WiFi connection.
2. Click the Sharing tab.
3. Check "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection".
4. Click OK.

Now you can connect computer B to computer A's internet connection via an Ethernet cable.

If later you want to restore normal use of the Ethernet port on computer A, undo the above by unchecking "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection".